# What is the role of the clobber list?

Tags: gcc, inline-assembly

I am newbie to inline-assembly, and I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around the "clobber list."  Would anyone be able to offer a simple explanation of when and why it's important to add registers to the clobber list?  Specifically, in this example...

```
volatile int a = 0;    
asm (
      "ldi r26, 42  \n" 
      "sts (a), r26 \n" 
      : : : "r26"
    );
```

...is the clobber list protecting what was previously stored in r26 from accidental deletion, or is it protecting the data that has just been written into r26 from being ignored by the compiler?  Perhaps both?

Also, is it correct to assert that the clobber list is not needed in "pure assembly" programming?

Comment: Clobber list only applies to GCC extended assembler Not pure assembly. The clobber list is a list of all the registers that are changed by the template but not listed in the input and output operands. Without a clobber list, an optimizing compiler may rely on the value in register `r26` being the same before and after the template is executed. if you don't tell it that the template potentially destroys the value in `r26`, it could lead to some difficult to track bugs if _GCC_ tries to use what it thinks is already in `r26` again.

Comment: Michael's pretty much got it (although strictly speaking 'inputs' can't be changed).  Two other (somewhat shorter) answers would be "This tells gcc that the value of the register is going to be changed by the asm, and that gcc shouldn't assume any particular value will be in it when the asm exits" or the one straight from the [gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Clobbers) "A comma-separated list of registers or other values changed by the AssemblerTemplate, beyond those listed as outputs."